Forget this sequence
(THIS STORY IS FICTIONAL)
One day, when I was at work, my worst enemy logged in to my computer and wrote these “meaningless” numbers written on my spreadsheet:
$ 25, 663, 669, 660, 440859, …$
After an hour trying to figure out what on earth these numbers mean, my worst enemy came to me and told me, “If you can figure out what the next number is, I will take it all back.”
Question: what is the next number in the number sequence above?
Hints:

 The sequence is not 100% mathematical.


 It is explicitly said that $654$ is not in the sequence.


 In a version of the sequence, the fifth term is $440781$. However, I don’t like it.

Giant hint (do not click unless you are absolutely stuck even with the other three hints)

 $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x<7 \\ 3 &   x\ge 7\end{cases} $$ $$ xf(x) = ?$$

